# What are the categories of Android??Ex. Java-j2ee,j2me,j2se

Tags: android

is there are any categories of Android??
Ex. java categories are J2ME,J2SE,J2EE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java categories you mention refer to various frameworks available by Sun now Oracle which differ by application use case, i.e. J2ME was for mobile devices, J2EE is server side. Since Android is geared toward a mobile platform: phones and tablets, there are only versions of Android and third-party libraries. Supporting what version depends on what you need and or what platform you are targeting (phones or tablets).